# Users as team members through a loop in elementor

Tags: loop, widgets, users

I am trying to create a loop in Elementor's theme builder that will display each user with the role of the Contributor or Author. I.E. When the admin of the website will add a new user with the above role, it will automatically display the newly added user on the About page, and at the same time that user will have access to the website.

This is to avoid duplication of work when the same team members might need to add articles to the website.

Thanks.
A possible workaround would be to create a new category (e.g. team-members) in posts and create a post for each member, but then the users will have to be entered separately which is time-consuming and prone to errors/inconsistencies.

Comment: You'll have to ask Elementor's support team about this. Third-party plugin support is [off topic](/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: I am not trying to get support as such. My question might actually lead to the development of a plugin (if such a one doesn't exist already).  All I am asking is if this kind of implementation is possible at all in the WordPress paradigm.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do this with using the dynamic content of Elementor Pro. With the loop grid, there is an option to do a custom query with the query id. From that you would just write. a PHP snippet to do exactly as you are looking for. It may be necessary to also create custom dynamic tags for each element that you want displayed in the loop grid as well. But definitely achievable.